# Should a style sheet object know about its target?

Tags: c#, user-interface

Here are three classes in my project. They work as expected. What I'm not sure of is the passing of the target into style sheet. What is going on is that I want the matrix as a whole to be left-aligned on the screen, but each entry to be centered within its column. The `GetHorizontalAlignmentQ` method accomplishes that.

`ExpressionStyleSheet` has a whole bunch of other subclasses for styling expressions in various situations.

This is currently the only case where the project actually makes use of the fact that targets pass themselves into their style sheets when getting style information. So I'm wondering whether or not that choice makes sense, and if not, what might be a different way to accomplish this type of subtlety. I am planning on expanding my use of style sheets (at the moment they are only used for expressions; no reason not to use them to style other views that have some kind of ViewModel), so it would not be difficult to imagine other cases where properties of the target could be useful.

```
public abstract class StyleSheet<TTarget>
{
  public abstract HorizontalAlignmentEnum? GetHorizontalAlignmentQ(TTarget target);
  public abstract VerticalAlignmentEnum? GetVerticalAlignmentQ(TTarget target);
  public abstract Color? GetBackgroundColorQ (TTarget taget);
  public abstract PCLFont GetFontQ (TTarget target, float scale = float.NaN);
  public abstract Color? GetTextColorQ(TTarget target);
  public abstract ThicknessF? GetPaddingQ(TTarget target);
  public abstract void Apply(TTarget target);
  public abstract LineBreakMode? GetLineBreakModeQ(TTarget target);
  public abstract String GetGhostedText(TTarget target);
  public abstract Color GetGhostedTextColor(TTarget target);
}

public class ExpressionStyleSheet: StyleSheet<AbstractExpressionUIState>
{
  public override void Apply(AbstractExpressionUIState target) {
    target.SetStyleSheet(this);
  }
  public override Color? GetBackgroundColorQ(AbstractExpressionUIState taget) {
    return Color.Black;
  }
  public override Color? GetTextColorQ(AbstractExpressionUIState target) {
    return Color.White;
  }
  public override LineBreakMode? GetLineBreakModeQ(AbstractExpressionUIState target) {
    return LineBreakMode.None;
  }
  public override PCLFont GetFontQ(AbstractExpressionUIState target, float scale = float.NaN) {
    return PCLFonts.SmallishEditableExpressionFont(scale);
  }
  public override ThicknessF? GetPaddingQ(AbstractExpressionUIState target) {
    PCLFont font = this.GetFontQ(target);
    float topBottom = (0.2f * font.PointSize).RoundToFloat();
    ThicknessF r = new ThicknessF (0, topBottom, 0, topBottom);
    return r;
  }
  public override HorizontalAlignmentEnum? GetHorizontalAlignmentQ(AbstractExpressionUIState target) {
    return HorizontalAlignmentEnum.Right;
  }
  public override VerticalAlignmentEnum? GetVerticalAlignmentQ(AbstractExpressionUIState target) {
    return VerticalAlignmentEnum.Center;
  }
  public override Color GetGhostedTextColor(AbstractExpressionUIState target) {
    return Color.Gray;
  }
  public override string GetGhostedText(AbstractExpressionUIState target) {
    return "";
  }
  public virtual void ApplyToAttributedString(AttributedString s, AbstractExpressionUIState state) {
    HorizontalAlignmentEnum? hAlignment = this.GetHorizontalAlignmentQ(state);
    VerticalAlignmentEnum? vAlignment = this.GetVerticalAlignmentQ(state);
    s.HorizontalAlignmentQ = hAlignment;
    s.VerticalAlignmentQ = vAlignment;
  }
}

internal class MatrixStyleSheet: ExpressionStyleSheet
{
  public override Color GetGhostedTextColor(AbstractExpressionUIState target) {
    return Color.White;
  }
  public override string GetGhostedText(AbstractExpressionUIState target) {
    return "0";
  }
  public override HorizontalAlignmentEnum? GetHorizontalAlignmentQ(AbstractExpressionUIState target) {
    if (target.IsText) {
      return HorizontalAlignmentEnum.Center;
    } else {
      return HorizontalAlignmentEnum.Left;
    }
  }
  public override VerticalAlignmentEnum? GetVerticalAlignmentQ(AbstractExpressionUIState target) {
    return VerticalAlignmentEnum.Center;
  }
  public override PCLFont GetFontQ(AbstractExpressionUIState target, float scale=1) {
    return PCLFonts.TextGridFont(scale);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's up with the overusage of nullables.

Comment: A style sheet may decline to answer a certain question, in which case the object would ask its parent's style sheet. Eventually there is a "style sheet of last resort" which is never supposed to be invoked but occasionally is (programmer error), and which always returns a non-null value.

Comment: Actually on further inspection, it looks like it used to work that way but no longer does, so I may want to take the nullables out.

Comment: The desire to improve code is implied for all questions on this site. Question titles should reflect the purpose of the code, not how you wish to have it reworked. See [ask].

Answer (score 2):

I think your concern is valid: it feels wrong to always pass a parameter which is not used in the majority of methods.

The thick base class looks problematic to me. It has many methods, and then multiple implementations; so here is what can happen over time:

- You will add more methods as you need, which will bloat all the implementations;
- You might find that you need some other parameters in some implementations, and you'll have to add them everywhere;
- [Liskov substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) gets violated in case some methods don't make much sense in some implementations;
- All this becomes heavy, difficult to read and maintain.

Instead, try to find a reasonable way to split the interfaces to small ones. It's hard to advise specific solutions, but one way would be to replace the multi-method interface with an interface holding a collection of specific style rules. You would end up with small classes, each one could accept any set of parameters out of available list, e.g.

```
public class MatrixHorizontalAlignmentRule : ITargetedStyleRule<HorizontalAlignmentEnum>
{
    public HorizontalAlignmentEnum GetStyle(AbstractExpressionUIState target) {
        if (target.IsText) {
            return HorizontalAlignmentEnum.Center;
        } else {
            return HorizontalAlignmentEnum.Left;
        }
    }
}
```

And then some way to combine them in style sheet collections.

Does that make sense in your scenario?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You answer looks good; I've linked the Wikipedia page for Liskov substitution - maybe you could also elaborate on how it gets violated.